# why sibling list is used to get the task_struct while fetching the children of a process

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Kernel task_struct looks like below.I am more interested in two members namely children and sibling  , so i have removed other elements from this kernel structure .

```
  struct task_struct{
        // some data elements .


          struct list_head children;      
              /* list of my children */

          struct list_head sibling;
              /* linkage in my parent's children list */
        //some data members 
        };
```

"children" is a doubly circular linked list of task_struct of the children of process .If I want to access the children from current process , I have to iterate over "children" list using macro "list_for_each" as below :

```
struct task_struct *task; 
struct list_head *list;
list_for_each(list, &current->children) { 
task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling); /* task now points to one of current’s children */ 
}
```

list_for_each will eventually initialize  "list " with next children .Now since we are iterating through children list , we should ideally subtract the offset of "children" list from "list" pointer to get the tast_struct address for the current process .**What is the reason we are passing "sibling" here which eventually a different list with different offset?** .

Please note : It is working code , all I want to understand is why sibling is used when children pointer should be used to calculate correct offset and hence task_struct address for the children .

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: @Olaf : could you please explain it with more details ?

Comment: @Olaf: AFAIK , container_of  is used to  retrieve the structure that contains the pointer of a given field. Here ,list_entry is somewhat similar macro which is used to get base address of structure giving address of a filed . So ,in list_entry , first elements contains the address of "children list " , so to get structure , i should pass children pointer to it not sibling .

Comment: Do you even understood the question ? What is the relation of container_of with this question .

Comment: `container_of` yields (it is a macro, thus no "return") the pointer to a `struct` given the type of the struct and a pointer a member. Do not manually subtract the `offsetof` a member. If not done properly, this may easily result in problematic aliasing. And for the actual problem: For your parents, you and your **siblings** are their *children**. But what is you brother for you? (hint: I already gave the answer)

Comment: @olaf : Again you missed the point , it is not about using "list_entry" or "container_of" , it is about the pointer passed to this macro . Above code is a working piece .Even if I use container_of , i need to pass sibling list only .

Comment: @Olaf: you sounds funny .Its great that you have decided not to give any more hint as hints given by you are not making any sense here .Let other answer and hopefully you will learn the right thing by doing so .

Comment: It does not make sense if you do not want to spend not even a little bit of thought on it. Instead you concentrate on not understanding. So, I'll leave it at that. You have the last word, enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! I am reading "Linux Kernel Development" and I got confused when reading the above code in Chap 3 (Page 30).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to organize data as linked list using `struct list_head` you have to declare **list root** and declare **list entry** for linkage. Both root and child entries are the same type (`struct list_head`). `children` entry of `struct task_struct` entry is a `root`. `sibling` entry of `struct task_struct` is a `list entry`. To see the differences, you have to read code, where `children` and `sibling` are used. Usage of `list_for_each` for `children` means what `children` is a `root`. Usage of `list_entry` for `sibling` means what `sibling` is a `list entry`.

You can read more about linux kernel lists [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-5).

**Question**: What is the reason we are passing "sibling" here which eventually a different list with different offset?

**Answer:**

If the list was created this way:

```
list_add(&subtask->sibling, &current->children);
```

Then

```
list_for_each(list, &current->children)
```

Will initialize list pointers to `sibling`, so you have to use `sibling` as parameter to list_entry. That's *how* linux kernel lists API designed.

But, If the list was created in another (**wrong**) way:

```
list_add(&subtask->children, &current->sibling);
```

Then you have to iterate the list this (**wrong**) way:

```
list_for_each(list, &current->sibling)
```

And now you have to use `children` as parameter for `list_entry`.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: That has nothing to do with linkage. Your answer is not clear. And what do you mean with "role"?

Comment: @alexander: Thanks you very much for the answer .+1 for that .Your answer is helpful .Although I have some query ,..childrren and sibling both are of same type (i.e. both are list ), how is it possible that one of them is root while other is a entry ? Any pointer will be really appreciable ?Do you mean when a entry is made for children in task struct , it is actually made in terms of its sibling?

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL: Link in the answer post clearly explains how list `root` and list `entry` have the same type `struct list_head`.

Comment: @Olaf: `*children* has list *root* role assigned` = `*children* is a *root*`. This is universal meaning of the word "role". `*sibling* has list *linkage* role assigned` = `*sibling* is used for *linkage* purposes`, that is for **link** given list entry with other ones. And this is true.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Thanks for the answer , Yes both root and entry has same type but they are two different data member in task struct (hence two different offset) .Now , if I want to get the pointer to task struct of a child , I should subtract offset of "children list " from address of "children "  , thats how list_entry works .My confusion was more on why "sibling " is passed here which is actually having different offset in task struct .only possibility is both have same address which i am not able to map correctly .

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thank you for explanation. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL: `current->children` is root, but you iterate over `.siblings` fields. You already know address of parent task (`current`), but you don't know address of children tasks. That is why you use `.siblings` field in `container_of()` macro. Note, that `.children` field of some *child* task is *list of children for that child*. This is comletely different tasks, for which `current` is grandparent.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Thanks for explanation .It is really very helpful .

Comment: @SACHIN GOYAL, I've updated the answer, hope it helps. list API is unusual for the first time, but, very powerfull.

Comment: @alexander : Yes , it is helpful .Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 4):

Following is the pictorial representation that might help someone in future. The top box represents a parent, and the bottom two boxes are it's children

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a picture in addition to the previous answers.
The same process can be both a parent and a child (as Parent1 on the picture), and we need to distinguish between these two roles.

Intuitively, if `children` of Parent0 would point to `children` of Parent1, then `Parent0.children.next->next` (green circle on the picture), which is the same as `Parent1.children.next`, would point to a child of Parent1 instead of a next child of Parent0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

But why not:

the list was created this way:

```
list_add(subtask, &current->children);
```

iterate in this way:

```
list_for_each(list, &current->children) {
  child = (struct task_struct *)list
}
```

Comment: ok, since list add defined as: void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)