# Linux how to convert task_list to list_head?

Tags: c, linux, process, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am trying to write a function that sums the pid of children processes recursively except the main process (if C was son of B which is son of A then I want pid(B)+pid(C))

So I wrote:

```
int get_children_sum_internal(const struct task_struct *current) {
    int result = current->pid;
    struct list_head *pos;
    list_for_each(pos, &current->children)
    {
        result+=pos->pid;
    }
    return result;
}

asmlinkage int get_children_sum(void) {
    if (list_empty(&current->children))
    {
        return;
    }
    return get_children_sum_internal(current);
}
```

But I am getting an error since current is from type task_list and pos is from type list_head. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-list-for-each-entry-continue.html

Comment: I don't think this fixes your issue, you still need to use `sibling` instead of `children` in the `list_entry` function. But what happens when you run the code? Does it work or do you see any errors?

Comment: I don't see any problems, why this is still buggy? I am using list_entry

Comment: @mr_calc I think you're misunderstanding how the `list_head` struct works in the kernel. Two ways to think about it. 1) What is `list_head` conceptually? It's an entry into a list. So when you get the `children` variable from the parent process, you're actually getting the entry of the first child in the list. So how do you get the next entry in the list from this first entry? The `list_for_each` set of functions is just moving your current entry `pos` forward by doing `pos= pos->next`.  But these are just entries (pointers), not the actual objects (in this case `task_structs`) themselves.

Comment: @mr_calc That's why you have to use `list_entry` (which is actually just a [macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h#L510) that uses `container_of`) to get the encapsulating object(process) that the entry refers to. Why do I say "encapsulating?" Because 2) from the perspective of the child, what is the entry it holds to the parent->children list? The child task_struct contains the siblings entry, which you can use to check the other siblings that share the same parent. What is a list of siblings, if not the children list of the parent. The lists are the same!

Comment: @mr_calc Also try not to edit your original post in ways that significantly alter the original question. Otherwise, the title, question, and answers will look confusing to other people coming to read this for the first time who don't understand the updates that you made.

Comment: [This post is being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407578/2605758)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kernel: how to iterate the children of the current process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207160/kernel-how-to-iterate-the-children-of-the-current-process)

Answer (score 2):

One issue you have (which may or may not be the only issue) is that in your `list_for_each`, the `pos` is type `list_head` but then you're using it as a `task_struct` by accessing `pos->pid`. You need to first get the encapsulating child `task_struct` that contains the `pos` by using the `container_of()` function.

From the [`include/linux/kernel.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L1) where [`container_of()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L700) is defined:

```
/**
 * container_of - cast a member of a structure out to the containing structure
 * @ptr:    the pointer to the member.
 * @type:   the type of the container struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the member within the struct.
 *
 */
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({
```

So in your case, I think doing `container_of(pos, task_struct, sibling)` will return the `task_struct` of the child that you can then access its `pid`. Notice that I used `sibling` instead of `children`, because at this step, the point of view is from the child. From the child's point of view, it sits on a sibling list, which from the parent's point of view, is its children list. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704761/why-sibling-list-is-used-to-get-the-task-struct-while-fetching-the-children-of-a) for more clarification).

---

Update: OP edited code in post to use `list_entry`, whereas before was accessing pid with
`pos->pid`. The `list_entry` function is another valid way to get encapsulating object. [Behind the scenes](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/list.h#L510), `list_entry` calls `container_of` anyway.

Comment: Plus I think you made a mistake, it should be children. I am sending a pointer to the father and then iterating over its children (why I need its siblings)?

Comment: @mr_calc `children` is the sentinel (head) node for the task's list of children. `sibling` is a non-sentinel node on the parent's list of children. So the `parent_task->children->next` points to the `child_task->sibling` node of the first child (if the list is non-empty). So `sibling` is the correct member to pass to `container_of`. It is more usual to use the `list_entry()` macro instead of the `container_of()` macro when dealing with `struct list_head` but they do the same thing.

Comment: I agree with @IanAbbott. To see it visually, look at the link I included at the end, someone drew a nice pictorial representation of what's going on, helped me understand the children vs. sibling relation.

Comment: Also, all you need is to add the `struct task_struct * child_task = container_of()` line right before you get the `pid`, then do `child_task->pid` for whatever you want.

Comment: @wxz If you mean this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128018/5264491 then I drew it. :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott I meant [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52617741/13020139), but I like yours too! :P

Comment: @IanAbbott siblings means brothers in English not child processes

Comment: @mr_calc The siblings are children of their common parent.

Comment: @mr_calc all you need to do to fix this error is change `list_entry(pos, struct task_struct, children)` to `list_entry(pos, struct task_struct, sibling)`.

Comment: @mr_calc however you need to go back to adding the pids which you seem to have removed in an update. But since this is separate from the original question relating to task_struct to list_head, you should open a new question about anything else if you are stuck.

Comment: " however you need to go back to adding the pids which you seem to have removed in an update." what you mean? I had a typo please see it

Comment: @mr_calc Yep, that typo was crucial.

Comment: Instead of deleting your question, you should have upvoted and answer then answer provider here